# detect whether wear app started with voice command or touch input

Tags: android, wear-os

In my wear app I would like to show different layout options based on whether app is started via a voice command or via a touch input. But I could not find any way to do this in docs.

The only possible way I can think of is to have two launchers. But I am looking for rather direct solution than creating multiple launchers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the activity log a bit, I found this:

When you click on an app in the Android Wear, this is logged:

> I/ActivityManager(446): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.lge.wearable.compass/.MainActivity} from uid 10002 on display 0

When you start the app with a voice command, this is logged:

> I/ActivityManager(446): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10008000 pkg=com.lge.wearable.compass cmp=com.lge.wearable.compass/.MainActivity} from uid 10002 on display 0

The difference is the `cat` or `category` parameter which includes `android.intent.category.LAUNCHER` as a value.

The following code in the `onCreate` function will differentiate whether the app is started with voice or by a user tap.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ....

    Set<String> categories = getIntent().getCategories();
    if(categories != null && categories.contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "app started via voice");
    }else{
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "app started with user tap");
    }

    ....
}
```

This currently works for my app scenario and hope it works for others too.

Comment: This looks good. Will you mark this as the answer? Also, I notice the touch one has an additional FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK flag, and a package set, which could also be checked.

Comment: I meant voice, not touch. Also, it is worth checking what comes out when app is selected from custom launcher like Wear Mini Launcher?

Comment: thanks @barkside I will check which flags are set when used from Launcher. Though I believe it should be same as starting the app with touch, but will check and update.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the answer from dhaval, I see that the category LAUNCHER is set when launching from a third-party launcher such as Wear Mini Launcher.

So instead, the following check will currently work (though may change in future Wear versions):

```
int flags = getIntent().getFlags();
String pkg = getIntent().getPackage();
if(pkg != null && (flags & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK) > 0) {
    Log.i("MUSICCONTROL", "app started via voice");
}else{
    Log.i("MUSICCONTROL", "app started with user tap");
}
```