# How to know if my app has been launched by Ok Google for a fully hands-free interaction

Tags: android, android-intent, google-now

I would like to know when my app has been launched by voice control ("Ok Google, launch MyApp") in order to present the users a different activity where they can interact using their voice.

The idea is "if the user launches the app using the Ok Google command, he probably wants a hands-free interaction".

Is there a way to know it? Intent categories and flags don't seem helpful.

Comment: This may be what you require.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480724/detect-whether-wear-app-started-with-voice-command-or-touch-input

Comment: Unfortunately not. Probably in that case it works since it is a wearable application (but it's only a guess, I've no experience in wearable app).
In my case the intent is always:
{ act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 pkg=my.app cmp=my.app/.MyActivity }
The only thing that changes is the flg field, but I can't see any connection with the launch mode.